# Map dictionary of wind directions to new column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe with wind directions, and I would like to create a new column mapping this infomation to the 16 segments of a meteorological compass, ie. N, NNE etc.. I have created a dictionary with the keys and values, but when I run the code my new column contains only NaN's. Here is a sample of my data and code. I am not sure exactly where I am going wrong... thanks for the help.

```
time    temperature windBearing windSpeed   ozone   pressure
0   2018-09-20 01:00:00 18.46   228 5.76    291.0   1014.5
1   2018-09-20 02:00:00 18.05   214 5.36    292.1   1014.5
2   2018-09-20 03:00:00 18.07   214 5.58    292.1   1014.3
3   2018-09-20 04:00:00 18.19   216 5.99    291.9   1013.9
4   2018-09-20 05:00:00 18.31   218 6.31    291.9   1013.5
```

Dictionary for angles:

```
compass = {
    range(349, 11) : 'N',
    range(11, 34) : 'NNE',
    range(34, 56) : 'NE',
    range(56, 79) : 'ENE',
    range(79, 101) : 'E',
    range(101, 124) : 'ESE',
    range(124, 146) : 'SE',
    range(146, 169) : 'SSE',
    range(169, 191) : 'S',
    range(191, 214) : 'SSW',
    range(214, 236) : 'SW',
    range(236, 259) : 'WSW',
    range(259, 281) : 'w',
    range(281, 304) : 'WNW',
    range(304, 326) : 'NW',
    range(326, 349) : 'NNW'    
}
```

Code being run:

```
df_met['compass'] = df_met['windBearing'].map(compass)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea but map works on a one-to-one level so you cant match on ranges.

instead, let us create a new data frame from your compass dictionary and merge the values on to your data frame.

```
df_dict = {}

for k,v in compass.items():
    for item in k:
        df_dict[int(item)] = v

wind_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict,orient='index').reset_index()
wind_df.columns=['windBearing', 'State']

new_df = pd.merge(wind,wind_df,on=['windBearing'],how='left')
```

---

```
print(new_df)

                       time  temperature  windBearing  windSpeed  ozone  \
0  0   2018-09-20 01:00:00         18.46          228       5.76  291.0   
1  1   2018-09-20 02:00:00         18.05          214       5.36  292.1   
2  2   2018-09-20 03:00:00         18.07          214       5.58  292.1   
3  3   2018-09-20 04:00:00         18.19          216       5.99  291.9   
4  4   2018-09-20 05:00:00         18.31          218       6.31  291.9   

   pressure State  
0    1014.5    SW  
1    1014.5    SW  
2    1014.3    SW  
3    1013.9    SW  
4    1013.5    SW
```

Comment: Thanks @Datanovice ! Do you know how I handle N? if I look at wind_df I see I have every possible section from the compass apart from N. This is clearly because the range is from 349 - 11 which I guess is not being handled well...

Comment: @ojp what do you expect in that column for N? since your going backwards you won't get anything

Comment: No worries I fixed it. range(349, 360) : 'N',
    range(0,11): 'N',